# Understanding import/no-cycle problem in eslint

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a some code in which eslint thrown an error of the type: `import/no-cycle`, but I don't understand where this cyclic dependency comes from.

The exact error thrown is: `ESLint: Dependency cycle via ../types:7=>./Jobs:1(import/no-cycle)`.

#### File 1. jobs/Jobs

```js
import { AuthJobs } from './Auth';

export interface IJobs {
  auth: AuthJobs;
  // ... more types
}
```

#### File 2. jobs/types

```js
import { IJobs } from './Jobs';

// This class doesn't use IJobs
export interface JobRunResponse<D, F = undefined> {
  data?: any;
  dataError?: JobErrorResponse<D>;
}
```

#### File 3. jobs/Auth/AuthJobs

```js
// Remember that in File 2, `JobRunResponse` doesn't use `IJobs`
// which at the same time is the one that uses `AuthJobs`
import { JobRunResponse } from '../types';

export class AuthJobs {
  // Class properties and methods
}
```

#### File 4. jobs/Auth/index

```js
// Here is where eslint thown the error
export { AuthJobs } from './AuthJobs';
```

#### Folder structure

```
jobs
├── Auth
│   ├── AuthJobs.ts
│   └── index.ts
├── Jobs.ts
└── types.ts
```

Trying to understand where cyclical dependency comes from, I can think that when `JobRunResponse` from `../types` it's imported in **File 3**(jobs/Auth/AuthJobs), implicitly import `IJobs` that use `AuthJobs`, but this doesn't make sense, I can't find any other explanation.

```
jobs/Jobs -> jobs/Auth/AuthJobs -> jobs/Auth/index -> jobs/Jobs
```

Comment: All code in an imported module is executed irrespective of what reference you are importing. If you dont give the references to import  eg`import {} from "./Jobs"`  `import {} from "./Auth"` and   `import {} from "../types"` the cyclic import will still exist.